# templating return type of function template argument

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to write some boilerplates for converting argument types before passing to functions of various signatures. The simplest example is taking a function that requires an `int*` and wrapping it to create one that takes a `std::vector`, as in the below example.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <void (*F)(int*, size_t)>
void tfunc_api(vector<int>& a)
{
  return F(&(a[0]), a.size());
}

void reset(int* a, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<int> foo = {1,2,3,4};
    tfunc_api<reset>(foo);

    for (auto e: foo)
        cout << e << endl;
}
```

I'm using a function template argument as I though this was the easiest way to deal with different signatures e.g. `void (*F)(int*, int*, size_t)`.

If I now want to create a wrapper for a similar function with a different return type, e.g.

```
int sum(int* a, size_t n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

then I could write a new specialization of `tfunc_api` for a template argument `int (*F)(int*, size_t)`.

However it would be more convenient to just template the return type. All my attempts at introducing additional template parameters have failed. Is this possible and if so, how? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++17, a super simple solution is `auto`:

```
template <auto (*F)(int*, size_t)>
auto tfunc_api(vector<int>& a)
```

Or even more generic:

```
template <auto F>
auto tfunc_api(vector<int>& a)
```

The more generic approach is useful for not limiting to function pointer, and can be used with other callables as well such as capturing lambdas. There may be a downside with less obvious error message in case of calling with wrong signature.

In C++14, I would pass the callable as a regular parameter, rather than template parameter:

```
template <class Fun>
auto tfunc_api(vector<int>& a, Fun F)

// call
tfunc_api(foo, sum);
```

Comment: I am stuck with `c++14` for the moment, but am ok with verbose.

Comment: Oh cool that makes sense, And the other arguments determine the signature of `Fun`. Many thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there a way to retain `(*F)(...)` as a template parameter in C++14 and do what OP wants?

Comment: One downside of passing the callable as a regular argument is you can no longer take the address of the specific `tfunc_api`. The original context for this question required this, so like @Evg i am also curious.

Comment: @ChrisD Shouldn't `&tfunc_api<decltype(sum)>` work?

Comment: That won't give me an e.g. `void (*)(vector<int>&)` will it? The actual context is implementing some python wrappers with pybind11, and needing to write endless wrapper functions that took a `pybind11::buffer`, extracted the underlying pointer, and then passed it to the c++ function. The [mechanism](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html#creating-bindings-for-a-simple-function) that generates the python bindings takes a pointer to the wrapper function as an argument.

Comment: @ChrisD `void (*)(vector<int>&)` will be `Fun` i.e. the type of `F`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lambda instead of templated function to do it in C++14 non-verbose:

```
auto tfunc_api = [] (auto F, vector<int>& a)
{
  return F(&(a[0]), a.size());
};

void reset(int* a, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 0;
    }
}

int sum(int* a, size_t n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<int> foo = {1,2,3,4};

    cout << tfunc_api(sum, foo) << endl;

    tfunc_api(reset, foo);
    for (auto e: foo)
        cout << e << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way to do it in C++14 keeping `F` as a template parameter is to introduce a type template parameter and then use `decltype`:

```
template<class T, T F>
auto tfunc_api(std::vector<int>& a)
{
  return F(&a[0], a.size());
}

std::cout << tfunc_api<decltype(sum), sum>(foo);
```

Looks ugly, but works.